Proca lagrangian equations of motion
In his book Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model, Matthew D. Schwartz postulates the Lagrangian for a massive spin 1 field (eq. 8.23):
\begin{equation}
\mathcal L=\frac{a}{2}A_\nu \partial_\mu\partial^\mu A^\nu+\frac{b}{2}A_\mu\partial^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu+\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\mu A^\mu.\tag{8.23}
\end{equation}
He then states that the corresponding equation of motion is
\begin{equation}
a \, \partial_\nu\partial^\nu A^\mu + b \, \partial^\mu\partial_\nu A^\nu + m^2 A^\mu = 0.\tag{8.21}\end{equation}
When I apply the Euler-Lagrange equations, I get a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the first two terms, because
$$\frac{\delta \mathcal{L} }{\delta \, \partial A^\mu} = 0.$$
Where am I making a mistake wrong?
UPDATE: I think the mistake I was making was trivially that I wasn't using the full version of the EL equation involving higher derivates:
$$ 0~\approx~\frac{\delta S}{\delta\phi}
~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial\phi} 
-\sum_{\mu} \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)} + \sum_{\mu\leq \nu} \frac{d}{dx^{\mu}} \frac{d}{dx^{\nu}} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi)} - \ldots,\tag{A} $$
(see this SE post: Lagrangian and Integration by Parts)

You may want to double check the greek indices.

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565594/2451
